# Is there a way to use a general purpose table structure for HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html-table

In my project, I am using a lot of HTML pages where I am using table structures for better formatting the fields in the page. Now say for page A, I have written the following code:

```
    <div align="center">
    <u>Create User</u><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                User-name
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
```

Now for a different page I may need to use 3 table rows to show all the fields in the page. So the basic structure is same in both the pages i.e. I am opening a div-opening table-opening table row- Opening table cells and closing them in the same order.

The only thing that will be different in the pages are number of table rows required. So I was wondering is there any functionality present so that I can create the pages easily without writing the same code again and again. It may act like a function which will take number of rows required. Is there any such functionality?

Comment: Use an HTML editor with the ability to use templates/macros. There does not appear to be a need to involve JavaScript for the creation of the table and/or contents. (Also, consider *not* using tables for this layout.)

Comment: Doing layouts with table markup has been a deprecated practice for many years now.

Comment: @Pointy, Can you let me know if the practice of using table is deprecated, what should be the ideal way to achieve the functionality?

Comment: Well it's a big subject, one about which countless blog posts have been made over the last 10 years. The answer is that `<table>` structures should be used for truly tabular data presentation, and not for the purposes of arranging content on the page. You can use CSS to adjust the presentation of markup that more closely describes the nature of your content. (You can even use CSS to make other markup be displayed as if it were table cells!)

Comment: To replace tables you can use DIVs or SPANs with style "float: left" or with fixed width/height. But in some cases the table way is easier, and by the way, tables were invented for layout management back ago.. But with DIVs and CSS you can make the same layout with less DOM elements (better web page performance) but you have to do a little more work.

Comment: @Fenistil no, `<table>` was invented for presenting tabular data, as is common in (for example) research papers. People simply started *using* `<table>` for layout and CSS was developed later.

Comment: @Pointy: Both of us are right, according to the HTML 3.2 Reference (where tables were introduced) it is said "Tables [...] can be used to markup tabular material or for layout purposes." :)

Comment: @Fenistil well I didn't say it wasn't the committee itself that coopted the facility :)  I recall thinking how cool it seemed at the time to have such a flexible layout tool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML there is no function to do that. But if you can use PHP or JavaScript you can make a function to "render" your HTML.

For example, in PHP (server side):

```
<?php

function MakeTR($title, $name) {
  print('<tr><td>'.$title.'</td><td><input type="text" name="'.$name.'"><br></td></tr>');
}

MakeTR('User-Name:','username');
MakeTR('Password:','pass');
MakeTR('Email:','email');

?>
```

Or you can do almost the same with JavaScript (client side):

```
<script>
    function MakeTR(title, name) {
        document.write('<tr><td>'+title+'</td><td><input type="text" name="'+name+'"><br></td></tr>');
    }

    MakeTR('User-Name:','username');
    MakeTR('Password:','pass');
    MakeTR('Email:','email');
</script>
```

Comment: The client–side code would be much better using DOM methods rather than *document.write* (and variable with names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructor functions).

Comment: @RobG: Yes I know, it was only a sample to show the way. The best way would be the jQuery with DOM element creating, or the PHP's one.

Comment: No need for jQuery either, very simple to make a small DOM element factory. But doing it on the server is by far the better solution. ;-)